# pointer arithmetic and an anonymous variable

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to move between values anonymously with a pointer without using an array. The code below is a *xptr=10; stands in line. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

-If it's not possible in c, you can reply in other languages. Thank you from now.-

```c
    #include <stdio.h>

    void main()
    {
        int x=5;    
        int *xptr =&x;
        printf("x value: %d\n", *xptr); 
        printf("x address %p\n", xptr);
        xptr++;
        *xptr=10;
        printf("1. new value: %d\n", *xptr);
        printf("1. new address: %p\n", xptr);
        xptr++;
        *xptr =15;
        printf("2. new value: %d\n");
        printf("2. address: %p\n", xptr);
        xptr--;
        printf("(?)we return 1. new value: %d", *xptr);
    }
```

Comment: Why did you use the java and c# tags?

Comment: Because, If it's not possible in c, you can reply in other languages.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to accomplish such a thing? If possible, this would be an implementation detail. What interface or functionality would you expect this to perform?

Comment: you're trying to access not allocated memory, it is undefined behaviour in all languages

Comment: I'm trying to discover a method where I can go back and forth between values without using arrays

Comment: variables are not supposed to be placed continuously in memory (some of them could be even not in memory, but in registers), only arrays give such guarantee, so it is impossible without arrays

Comment: Why do you not want to use arrays?

Comment: because i got an assignment asking me to do catalan numbers without using array and recursive functions. . I can write this assignment with array and recursive functions, but I could not do otherwise.

Comment: (e.g.) `int x = 5; int *xptr = &x; // use *xptr` is okay. But, doing: `++xptr; *xptr = 10;` is UB (undefined behavior) because we no longer know what `xptr` points to. It might be the return address of the caller of `main` (e.g.). So, changing anything at this point is UB.

Comment: Even if this did work, doing so would be against the spirit of your assignment. You are expected to iteratively produce the catalan numbers -- finding the relationship between C_n and C_(n+1)

Comment: Or, just check the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) to find the relationship ([picture here](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/15115359a55c1ff29d7d56b61bd5c824e7c6b668)). Store one variable with the current Catalan number, one variable with the current value of n, and calculate the new value from the old value.

Comment: it said don't use recursive and array...

Comment: Catalan(n) = (2n choose n) / (n + 1). The iterative formula is easy to derive from that. See  Wikipedia.

Comment: Use a loop then. You're going to have to clarify with the instructor exactly what they want. Or, you can calculate each one from scratch. Although if a loop is recursive, then calculating from scratch will kind of be as well.

Comment: Thanks for your time and attention

Answer (score 1):

In the code as written, I see no reason to expect (&x)+1 to point to anything meaningful.  Depending upon what a compiler happened to place in storage immediately following `x`, writing to that address may have catastrophic effects.

In the C language as originally documented in the 1974 C Reference Manual, implementations would often specify how objects were laid out in greater detail than is required by the Standard.  If, for example, one were to do something like:

```
int test(n)
  int n;
{
  int *p = &n;
  while(--n >= 0)
    out_number(*++p);
}
```

and invoked the function as:

```
test(3, 10, 20, 30);
```

the effect on the kinds of machines for which C was designed would be to output the numbers 10, 20, and 30.

Although many C compilers used to use argument-passing conventions that would make such code work reliably, modern compilers often use other conventions that would not be compatible with such techniques, but are more efficient when processing programs that don't require them.  Even in cases where a programmer would know that two objects are placed consecutively, many compilers will assume that there is no way a programmer could know such things, and thus that no programmer would ever care about what happens if code uses a reference to one object to access the storage of another seemingly-unrelated object.